# JSure Javascript Static Analysis Tool

Tags: javascript

Does JSure, a Javascript Static Analysis Tool, run on Windows ?

Comment: Isn't that a **Java** tool, not JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to run on oCaml, and for oCaml there is a windows distribution, so it seems to be possible. You may download oCaml here:
http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html I've got no experience at all using oCaml or this tool, you're more or less on your own from there.

However if javascript quality checking is your objective you might find that these tools are easier to implement.

**JSLint:** the original javascript linter by Douglas Crockford
http://www.jslint.com/

**JSHint:** A more real-world fork of jslint
http://jshint.com/

And two framework based approaches:
**jQuery lint:** A jquery run-time code linter
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/

**Google closure linter:** To check google closure code against the google closure javascript style
http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/

Comment: In the above JSHint and JSLint are switched.